# Accessing SQLite3 modes from Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I came across various similar questions, but I can't figure it out.

how to I use the .import command from ruby? I mean, when you run the sqlite3, you can type in commands, like this:

```
sqlite3> .import file table
```

so, how can i import file this way into sqlite3 in-memory database and performing sql on it?

my "not-so-pseudocode" (which not work):

```
require 'sqlite3'
begin
    db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
    db.execute ".import file table"   #<----- not working, obviously

rescue SQLite3::Exception => e

    puts "Exception occurred"
    puts e

ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

Answer (score 0):

".import" and the rest of the "dot" commands are not part of the sqlite3 library, but are part of the sqlite3 command-line tool.  Therefore, you must either implement what the command does in your program, or invoke the "sqlite3" *program* from ruby just like you would any other external program, using e.g. system or other means.